# Detox and Apollo v3 crash

Tags: react-native, apollo, detox

**Description**

We recently upgraded from Apollo v2 to v3 in our React Native app. Ever since our Detox tests have been failing on Bitrise CI but they work fine locally. We get this odd crash report when we run them on Bitrise CI.

I can run old code and it passes fine but any new code using Apollo v3 fails.

Note: We have some websockets / subscriptions that might be the cause of this. Seems like it doesn't release the lock here: `willReleaseLock`.

**Logs**

```
detox[24921] INFO:  Group message notification tests: should log in
detox[24921] ERROR: [Detox.js/APP_CRASH] App crashed in test 'Group message notification tests should log in', here are the crash details: 
Signal 5 was raised
(
    0   Detox                               0x000000010a612bd5 __DTXHandleSignal + 59
    1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff5e7305fd _sigtramp + 29
    2   ???                                 0x0000000113e51a60 0x0 + 4628748896
    3   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff316bd2c6 JSC::JSLock::willReleaseLock() + 246
    4   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff316bd174 JSC::JSLock::unlock(long) + 68
    5   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff316bd461 JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks(JSC::VM*) + 257
    6   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff30d37687 JSC::JSCallbackObject<JSC::JSNonFinalObject>::call(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::CallFrame*) + 599
    7   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff313fb9e1 JSC::handleHostCall(JSC::JSGlobalObject*, JSC::CallFrame*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallLinkInfo*) + 353
    8   JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff313fb34f operationLinkCall + 127
    9   ???                                 0x000027b243202d67 0x0 + 43646583844199
    10  ???                                 0x000027b24339b6e5 0x0 + 43646585517797
    11  ???                                 0x000027b2433987c4 0x0 + 43646585505732
    12  ???                                 0x000027b2436c021c 0x0 + 43646588813852
    13  ???                                 0x000027b243658b6e 0x0 + 43646588390254
    14  JavaScriptCore                      0x00007fff30cdaf09 llint_entry + 104453
```

**Versions**

```
    "detox": "^17.3.6",
    "react-native": "0.63.3",
    "@apollo/client": "^3.2.9",
```

[image]

Comment: At least from the stack trace, it doesn’t look like it’s related to Detox. Something bad is going on in the JS or in JavaScriptCore itself.

Comment: Symbolicate the symbols from your own app to have more clarity of what it is doing.

Comment: @LeoNatan I added a picture of the symbolicated logs but it doesn't give anymore clarity

Comment: @LeoNatan We think it might be happening in Bitrise CI and not locally because the simulator isn't open in CI. Is there any way to force detox to open the simulator app in CI?

Comment: @LeoNatan We added a script to open the simulator in CI and see if that works:
open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app

Comment: @LeoNatan I think we figured it out, we recently added a timer on our phone authentication screen. 

Detox synchronization is probably:
Keeping track of timers and waiting until they expire or are cancelled

But if the app is in headless mode that timer probably never expires as we wait until the counter goes from 30 to 0 seconds before we expire it or when the screen unmounts. But detox probably isn't moving on.

Comment: Headless simulator has the full runtime behind working just the same, so that’s not your problem.

Comment: @LeoNatan Even if that timer is not being cancelled until after 30 seconds or maybe not at all? That seems like a long time for the UI to be held up for Detox.

Comment: @LeoNatan We also think maybe its something to do with this Modal component:
https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal crashing the app.

Comment: Hi @LeoNatan I'm wondering if you can provide any more help. I added the symbolcated logs to the stackoverflow issue. Let me know if you have any ideas or what I can provide for more clarity.

Comment: It looks a crash inside JavaScriptCore. I don’t know what is causing it. Likely something in the JS.